# Bulk Insert Error using Knex.js: bind message supplies X parameters, but prepared statement "" requires Y

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, knex.js

When using Knex.js to do a large INSERT to PostgreSQL 11.2,

```
await knex(myTable).insert(largeArray);
```

we get the error

> bind message supplies 47078 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 9353190

**Question:** Is there a way to do large inserts in Knex.js without the use of binding? Or is there a parameter in PostgreSQL that we can change to allow large inserts like these?

I believe I have used Sequelize.js ORM to perform similarly sized inserts (1/2 the size of this) without such errors, but prefer not to use an ORM for our current purposes.

*Using knex 0.20.9, Node.js 12.14.1, PostgreSQL 11.2, TimescaleDB 1.6.0, Ubuntu 18.04.3*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the data in batches. There is utility function called `batchInsert()` in knex for helping to do it. Databases has limited statement size / number of bindings. Sequelize probably does batching internally, since it cannot override the limits casted by database server.

If you prefer not to use ORM you could try `objection.js` it is more like an advanced helper library on top of knex for commonly needed stuff instead of real ORM.